# Affinity Designer add on fonts

Tags: fonts, mac, affinity-designer

Is it possible to add or purchase fonts for Affinity Designer? 
I'm running Affinity on Mac - Sierra 10.12.4 if relevant,
 and I'd like to know if I'm able to use fonts other than the out of box choices.

Comment: Any fonts installed on your Mac should be available to Designer. Have you tried installing any fonts?

Comment: I have not, I will try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any font you install on your system should be available on Affinity. You just need to install them normally, by [using fontbook or dragging to your system's font fodler](https://www.fontspring.com/support/installing/how-do-i-install-fonts-on-my-mac).

Comment: Or using an actual proper font manager :)